# Highstock hide tooltip crosshair when screen resize

Tags: highcharts

I want hide tooltip and crosshair when screen resize but when I call method 
this.chart.tooltip.hide();
Only tooltip hide , I dont see any method help hide crosshair.

Comment: I think you are looking for `tooltip: {
        crosshairs: false
    },`

Comment: Hi Codeer that is option when create a chart not a method to call when screen resize

Comment: Well your question is kind of unclear. Could you please elaborate a bit more? (By adding in your code for example)

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling around I found out that this works (for a button):

```
$('button').click(function() {
  chart.update({tooltip: {enabled: false}, xAxis: {crosshair: false}}, true);
})
```

This disables the tooltip, and at the same time disables crosshair.

Note that setting `tooltip: {crosshairs: false}` in the update function will not do anything. Ref: [tooltip.crosshairs](https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/tooltip.crosshairs).

> crosshairs: Mixed
>   Since 4.1, the crosshair definitions are moved to the Axis object in order for a better separation from the tooltip. See xAxis.crosshair.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/q04df7wy/12/